# Setting Drawable on already created ImageView works, but not in a new ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I'm trying to add dynamically ImageViews to a RelativeLayout that is already created. However, the images aren't being displayed.

This is the relevant part of my `layout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/servicesRelativeLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/servicesImgView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/campsite_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my code:

```
RelativeLayout servicesRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.servicesRelativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
layoutParams.setMarginStart(44);
layoutParams.setMarginEnd(10);

for (String availableService : getServices()) {
    @DrawableRes int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(
        "service_" + availableService.toLowerCase(),
        "drawable",
        getPackageName()
    );

    if (resID != 0) {
        ImageView availableServiceImgView = new ImageView(this);
        availableServiceImgView.setImageResource(resID);
        availableServiceImgView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        servicesRelativeLayout.addView(availableServiceImgView);
    }
}
```

Annotations:

- The ImageViews are being created, and being added to `servicesRelativeLayout` (tested with the debugger).
- resID exists, and I have tested it populates an existing ImageView (`servicesImgView`) with that resource ID.
- `servicesImgView` gets displayed
- If I do `servicesRelativeLayout.removeAllViews();` before the for loop, it removes `servicesImgView` and add the new view, as expected, but shows nothing

Any idea about why these Drawables aren't being displayed? I tried using `Drawable.createFromStream` to load assets instead of Drawables, but didn't really worked. I guess I'm missing something related with the addition of dynamic ImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this resource exist or not.

```
"service_" + availableService.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: As I commented in the annotations block, it does exist. I check it in the IF block (getResources().getIdentifier returns 0 if the resource doesn't exist). Besides, I checked it with an existing ImageView, and it replaces the Drawable being displayed.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea I tested your code it`s working fine.Just i replace  "service_" + availableService.toLowerCase()  to my drawable.

Comment: As I explained, resID is not 0, ergo, it's a valid resource ID. However, I tried before using an ImageResource with R.drawable.service_an_existing_service, and it doesn't work with new ImageViews. But it works using the ImageView that is already created when the XML is loaded using setContentView. It's not working for dynamic ImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

The 'guilty' code was the one related with the LayoutParams. Removing the line made the drawables to be displayed:

```
availableServiceImgView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Somehow, I'm not building the LayoutParams in the right way.

I decided to change the RelativeLayout for a LinearLayout, and I tweaked the margins to be as I wanted to be:

```
LinearLayout servicesLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.servicesLinearLayout);
servicesLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
layoutParams.setMarginStart(10);
layoutParams.setMarginEnd(10);
```

I assume I don't fully understand the RelativeLayout class, because the images weren't displayed at all, not even in a wrong way.